# Differing frequency count between grpel and quanteda textstat_frequency

Tags: r, quanteda

I was validating some data and I noticed that when I use grepl to search for a term using `sum(grepl('time',x = df$Comments))` (where df is a simple data.frame where each row contains a different tweet) and I try to compare that to `textstat_frequency` in the quanteda package using

```
df %>% corpus(text_field='Comments') %>% dfm(tolower = T,
                                             remove = stop_words,
                                             remove_punct = T,
                                             remove_symbols = T,
                                             remove_numbers = T) %>% textstat_frequency()
```

I get two different results

with grepl, i'm getting 2718 and with quanteda I'm getting:

```
 feature frequency rank docfreq group
  time      2879    1    2113   all
```

Is textstat_frequency not the way to go about this?

Comment: There are a few reasons why this could happen. Very hard to tell without the data. Is there a small subset of it that you can target and share here where there is a difference?

Comment: One thing is that your regex will only capture "time", while your `quanteda` code is converting everything to lowercase, so its including "Time" and "time" (and so on). That very well may be the cause for the additional counts. You could try `tolower = FALSE` and see what that does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two likely reasons.

1. `grepl()` only counts a `TRUE` if a match occurs once in a document (or character element of the `Comments` vector).  `textstat_frequency()` counts the token each time that it occurs.  That's one likely reason why the latter counts more instances than the former.
2. You have uppercase occurrences of "time" in your text field, which are not matched by the way you use `grepl()`, while by default, `dfm()` has `tolower = TRUE` as the default.  So `textstat_frequency()` counts uppercase occurrences, while your use of `grepl()` does not.  However, you can change this by using `grepl(..., ignore.case = TRUE)`.

Example:

```r
txt <- c("This time is new.", "Time, time, time.", "Time is on our side.")

sum(grepl("time", txt))
## [1] 2
sum(grepl("time", txt, ignore.case = TRUE))
## [1] 3

library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.1.2

dfm(txt) %>%
  textstat_frequency(n = 1)
##   feature frequency rank docfreq group
## 1    time         5    1       3   all
```

If you want to match the counting behaviour via a regex-type solution, you could get it to work this way:

```r
stringi::stri_extract_all_fixed(txt, "time", case_insensitive = TRUE) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  length()
## [1] 5
```

but that will still have the disadvantage of not taking into account word boundaries, and so will still count "sometime" as "time".  Tokenization and using `textstat_frequency()` on the other hand will take into account the word boundaries, since it has tokenised the text, including words joined to punctuation characters like `time,` or `"time"`.

So `textstat_frequency()` is definitely the way to go about this.

Comment: interesting approaches. The reason I'm asking is because I built a shiny app that will plot the `textstat_frequency` then using plotly you can click on a term and that click triggers `DT:::DataTable` and using the click as input into the search so you can get a `kwic` like view of all the comments with that search term. There might not be a great way to do this right now given the limitations of the search function with the plotly event data